# Can anyone explain why I got unpacked error?

Tags: python

I try to create one list that contain all my 4 list. Then I use for loop to Iterate through that list to get all the element inside the loop and I get this error.

Here is my code:

```
x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test = split([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],3)
total = [x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test]
for x,y,z,i in total:
    print(x,y,z,i)
```

Here is my error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-acdb671f80e4> in <module>
     42 x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test = split([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],3)
     43 total = [x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test]
---> 44 for x,y,z,i in total:
     45     print(x,y,z,i)
     46 

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)
```

And for the split function it just the function that similar to split in **k_split** of **sklearn** library.

Here is my split function:

```
def split(xs,ys,k):
    if len(xs)%k !=0:
        raise TypeError("your split is uneven")
    else:
        xs = pd.DataFrame(xs)
        ys = pd.DataFrame(ys)
        data_split_xs = np.array_split(xs,k)
        data_split_ys = np.array_split(ys,k)
        train_set_x = []
        train_set_y = []
        test_set = []
        test_set_y = []

        for i in range(k):
            train_x = data_split_xs.copy()
            train_y = data_split_ys.copy()

            test = data_split_xs[i]
            test_y = data_split_ys[i]
            test_set_y.append(test_y)
            test_set.append(test)
            del train_x[i]
            del train_y[i]
            train_y = pd.concat(train_y,sort=False)
            train_x = pd.concat(train_x, sort=False)
            train_set_y.append(train_y)
            train_set_x.append(train_x)
            test_array_y =np.array(test_set_y)
            train_array_y = np.array(train_set_y)
            test_array=np.array(test_set)
            train_array_x = np.array(train_set_x)
        a,b,c = test_array.shape
        new_test_x = test_array.reshape(a,-1)
        d,e,f = train_array_x.shape
        new_train_x = train_array_x.reshape(d,-1)
        g,h,i = train_array_y.shape
        new_train_y = train_array_y.reshape(g,-1)
        j,k,l = test_array_y.shape
        new_test_y = test_array_y.reshape(j,-1)
        return new_train_x,new_train_y,new_test_x,new_test_y
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop logic is incorrect. Your loop iterates over each value in `total = [x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test]` and tries to unpack each value into four variables, `x,y,z,i`. So on the first iteration it attempts to unpack `x_train` into `x,y,z,i` but `x_train` only contains three values, hence the error message:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

i followed your code and i see what you would like to find is something like this;here is the correct loop

```
for xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest in zip(total[0], total[1], total[2], total[3]):
    print( xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest )
```

why did I put the indexes? because your tables are quite simply a **table of 4 tables**

in other words **'total'** is an array which **contains sub-array** so we cannot put it directly in the loop

if you visualized the **'total'** array here is their content in the output of your function :

```
[array([[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]], dtype=int64),
 array([[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]], dtype=int64),
 array([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]], dtype=int64),
 array([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]], dtype=int64)]
```

---

Note:

I advise you to replace this piece of code by this one that is more readable and more optimal:

```
new_test_x  = test_array.reshape(test_array.shape[0],-1)
new_train_x = train_array_x.reshape(train_array_x.shape[0],-1)

new_train_y = train_array_y.reshape(train_array_y.shape[0],-1)
new_test_y  = test_array_y.reshape(test_array_y.shape[0],-1)
```

Instead of what you did :

```
a,b,c = test_array.shape
new_test_x = test_array.reshape(a,-1)

d,e,f = train_array_x.shape
new_train_x = train_array_x.reshape(d,-1)

g,h,i = train_array_y.shape
new_train_y = train_array_y.reshape(g,-1)

j,k,l = test_array_y.shape
new_test_y = test_array_y.reshape(j,-1)
```

Comment: Welcome t SO; please mind your code snippets indentation, which matters in Python (edited).